# Is "Rapture" mentioned in the Book of Revelation?

Tags: revelation, rapture

In 1st Thessalonians Paul describes the Rapture:

1Th 4:13 through 17   KJV

> 13  But I would not have you to be ignorant, brethren, concerning them which are asleep, that ye sorrow not, even as others which have no hope.
>
> 14  For if we believe that Jesus died and rose again, even so them also which sleep in Jesus will God bring with him.
>
> 15  For this we say unto you by the word of the Lord, that we which are alive and remain unto the coming of the Lord shall not prevent them which are asleep.
>
> 16  For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the dead in Christ shall rise first:
>
> 17  Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, *to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord.*

Do any Denominations hold a consensus as to where in the Book of Revelation, this "Rapture" spoken by Paul is mentioned?

Comment: Not surprisingly, there is no one answer to this.  [There is a bit of disagreement on how to interpret the verses.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/what-are-the-different-views-regarding-the-order-of-events-for-end-times-prophec/4843#4843)

Comment: I edited the question to make it more specific but people are still misunderstanding the question. I think they read it as **"When will Rapture take place?"**, instead of **"Is Rapture found in Revelation?"**.

Answer (score 5):

This is the LCMS answer to questions concerning the Rapture:

The short answer is: On the Last Day.

When is the Last Day? We don't know. The last day will come "like a thief in the night," bringing destruction to unbelievers but salvation to believers (1 Thess. 5:1 - 10).

> **Q:  Does The Lutheran Church—Missouri Synod believe in the rapture?**
>
> A:  The answer to your question depends on what you mean by "the
>   rapture." The English word "rapture" is derived from the Latin
>   translation of the verb "caught up" in 1 Thess. 4:17 (rapiemur).
>   Lutherans certainly believe what Paul teaches in this passage, namely,
>   that those who are still living on earth when Christ returns visibly
>   on the last day "will be caught up" ("raptured") together with "the
>   dead in Christ" to "meet the Lord in the air."
>
> Some Christians teach, however, that the "rapture" will take place not
>   on the last day but in connection with an "invisible" coming of Christ
>   occurring before a seven-year period of "tribulation" on earth,
>   allowing Christians to "escape" this tribulation and then later return
>   to earth for a literal "1,000 year reign of Christ."
>
> Lutherans do not believe that these teachings are based on a proper
>   understanding of Scripture. Scripture teaches that all Christians will
>   endure varying degrees of "tribulation" until the last day, that
>   Christ will return only once (visibly) to "catch up" ("rapture") all
>   believers, living and dead, into heaven, and that all believers will
>   reign forever with him in heaven. Lutherans understand the "1000
>   years" of Rev. 20:11-15 to be a figurative reference to Christ's reign
>   here and now in the hearts and lives of believers, which will
>   culminate in our reigning with Christ forever in heaven following his
>   return on the last day.
>
> For more information, you may want to read the Synod's theological
>   commission report titled [The End Times: A Study of Eschatology and
>   Millennialism](http://www.lcms.org/Document.fdoc?src=lcm&id=417).

Comment: So, Rapture is mentioned in the Book of Revelation or not? The question is not asking when Rapture should take place. It is asking whether this idea is found in the Book of Revelation or not.

Comment: So the answer to the question, for Lutherans, is that Revelation *doesn't* speak of a secret rapture?

Answer (score 1):

When I was a pre-tribber I learned that the rapture was indicated at Rev 4:1, as is taught at this site.

http://ldolphin.org/kingdom/ch4.html

There are other views now, which are discussed on this paper.

http://www.tms.edu/tmsj/tmsj13h.pdf

Personally I don't believe the rapture is taught in Revelation, or even in the whole Bible. A close comparison of 1 Th 4 with 1 Co 15 shows that Paul is talking about the resurrection, not a separate "rapture."

> 1Th 4:16  For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the dead in Christ shall rise first: 
>   1Co 15:52  In a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trump: for the trumpet shall sound, and the dead shall be raised incorruptible, and we shall be changed.
>
> 1 Co 15:12  Now if Christ be preached that he rose from the dead, how say some among you that there is no resurrection of the dead? 
>   1Co_15:13  But if there be no resurrection of the dead, then is Christ not risen: 
>   1Co_15:21  For since by man came death, by man came also the resurrection of the dead. 
>   1Co_15:42  So also is the resurrection of the dead. It is sown in corruption; it is raised in incorruption:

Look for the word "rapture" in your Bible. I can't find it in my KJV. I do find "resurrection."

Answer (score 0):

### Revelation 14 is not a description of the Rapture.

This harvest occurs with a sickle!  Have you ever thought about being harvested with a sickle?  A sickle cuts, so being harvested with it would be violent!
We then read verse 19 when the sickle is *thrust* (another word bringing to mind a violent removal), the vine of the Earth is gathered and cast into the great winepress of the wrath of God - from which blood comes forth, up to the horses bridles!  How can this violent series of events be a Rapture?

#### The Rapture in Revelation occurs in Rev 4:1

A door is opened in heaven, a voice as it were a trumpet saying, "Come up hither..." and immediately John was in the spirit.

- A trumpet like 1 Corinthians 15:52; this trumpet is not the same as the 7th trumpet in Rev 11:15 since that trumpet is a trumpet of judgment on the unrighteous, same as all the other trumpets in that section, with the great voices in heaven announcing the coming of Christ's earthly kingdom.

This happens right after the letters to the 7 churches (the church age).  John was told to write 3 things in this book of prophecy:

1. the things which he has seen
2. the things which are
3. and the things which must come to pass, Rev 1:19.

   The things which he has seen was the vision of Jesus vs 12-17 (as well as the time he spent with him on Earth which he wrote about in Rev 1:1-8);
   The "things which are" are the 7 letters to the 7 churches (the church age);
   The rest of Revelation is the things to come.

#### What is "Rapture?"

The word English word "rapture" is not in our English translations, but in the King James Bible, the NIV, and the NASB.  In 1 Thess 4:17 you find the phrase "caught up" which is translated from the word "rapio" in the Latin texts, and from the word "harpazo" from the Greek texts. The English language translations we read today are from those Latin and Greek texts.

1. The Greek word "harpazo" literally means "to  seize" "catch up," or
   "snatch away."
2. The Latin word "rapio" means  "to seize" or "snatch."

   This is exactly how it is translated in the King James Bible, the NIV, and the NASB.  (Sorry, those are the only English versions I use). The word "rapio" or "harpazo" should create an image of being an instantaneous event!
   It is the same word used in Acts 8:39 when Phillip was "caught up" by the Spirit of the Lord immediately after he baptized the eunuch and the eunuch "saw him no more" and then Phillip was found in Azotus.
   It is likewise used in 2 Corinthians 12:2-4 when Paul was "caught up" to the third heaven.

#### The word *rapture* does appear in the Bible ...

... if you read the text in the original language in which it was created!  Besides, it's just semantics, it doesn't matter which word or words you use, the act of being "caught up" or "raptured" is still there no matter what you call it.

Comment: Monica, I have edited your answer to get it out of the "wall of text format."  Please review it and edit it again to make sure that your intended meaning is retained.  Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how Q&A sites work.  Also, please review [how we are different from other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/24204).

Comment: This answer does not answer my question concerning the rapture and Revelation.

Answer (score -1):

### Harvest of the Earth is the Rapture

[Many scholars](http://crossbearer-brian.tripod.com/id240.htm) believe that the *Harvest of the Earth* in Revelation 14 is the Rapture of the Church.

> **Revelation 14:14-16, NIV**
>
> I looked, and there before me was a white cloud, and seated on the
>   cloud was one like a son of man with **a crown of gold** on his head and a
>   **sharp sickle** in his hand. Then another angel came out of the temple
>   and called in a loud voice to him who was sitting on the cloud, “Take
>   your sickle and reap, because the time to reap has come, for the
>   harvest of the earth is ripe.” So he who was **seated on the cloud swung
>   his sickle over the earth**, and the earth was harvested.

From [The People's New Testament (1891) by B. W. Johnson](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/pnt/revelation/14.htm)

> *14:14 Upon the cloud one sat like the Son of Man*. Jesus has himself
>   said that the Son of man shall be seen coming upon the clouds of
>   heaven (Mt 24:30). John here sees the Son of Man sitting upon a white
>   cloud. The Savior said that his coming shall be with great power and
>   glory (Mt 24:30). John now sees upon the head of the Son of man a
>   golden crown. The Savior said that he will send his angels to gather
>   the elect (Mt 24:31). John hears an angel bid him who sat upon the
>   cloud, to reap the earth, for its harvest was ripe.
>
> *14:15 Thrust in thy sickle, and reap*. There is gathered first the
>   ripened harvest of the elect of God. It is an angel that came out of
>   the temple of God as a messenger of God, carrying to the Son the
>   Father's command to gather the elect from the four corners of the
>   earth. Then a longing, waiting Church, loving the appearing of the Son
>   of man (2Ti 4:8), shall first be gathered into the heavenly garner.
>   The ripe sheaves are gathered.
>
> *14:16 And the earth was reaped*. The harvest of souls is ended forever.
>   But those who are upon the earth shall not be taken before them that
>   are asleep (1Th 4:15). At the voice of the archangel the dead shall
>   wake from their long sleep in the embrace of earth. Death shall be
>   swallowed up in victory (1Co 15:54). See also Re 14:13.

The sample pictures will give a better idea of how it would look like.

[image: The harvest of the earth]

[image: Rapture]

Important points from Apostle John's vision:

1. **The Son of man represents Jesus Christ**

   > “You have said so,” Jesus replied. “But I say to all of you: From now
   >   on you will see the **Son of Man** sitting at the right hand of the Mighty
   >   One and **coming on the clouds** of heaven.” (Matthew 26:64, NIV)
2. **Jesus was sitting on the cloud:** Jesus did not set his foot on the earth but was sitting on the cloud and swung his sickle over the earth. This would indicate that Jesus did not come to judge the earth(Second Coming) but only to take away the believers (Rapture) to meet with Jesus on the clouds. Only those who are harvested will witness this.
3. **Jesus wore only one crown:** This would mean that Jesus was not in all his glory. Compare this with `Revelation 19:12` where the rider on the white horse (Jesus) wore many crowns, which would mean "with all his glory". Hence, the harvest and the rider on the white horse are two different events. This would mean that the Rapture(Harvest) comes first and then the Second Coming.

The sequence of events would be

1. The Anti-Christ (Revelation 13)
2. The 144,000 Israelites (Revelation 14:1-5)
3. **The Harvest or Rapture** (Revelation 14:14-16)
4. The wrath of God (Revelation 15,16)
5. The fall of Babylon (Revelation 17,18)
6. **The Second Coming** (Revelation 19)
7. The Millennium (Revelation 20:1-6)
8. The Judgement Day (Revelation 20:7-15)
9. The New Earth (Revelation 21)

Comment: The linked Crossbearer website has some misleading information. It lists Gill, Henry, and Wesley as supporters of post-tribulation rapture, when in fact they lived and died before the doctrine of the rapture was ever formulated.

Comment: Wesley, for example, understood the being "caught up" in terms of [judgment day](http://new.gbgm-umc.org/umhistory/wesley/sermons/15/), and not as a distinct event of "harvest" or "rapture".