# What is the biblical basis for Historical Premillennialism?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology

> **Related:**
>
> - [What are the differences between the different millenialisms?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-millenialisms)
> - [What is the biblical basis for Dispensational Premillennialism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7044/194)

[Historical Premillennialism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historic_Premillennialism) is a view of the end times that (very, very basically) says that evil will continue to increase (but the church will hold strong), then Christ will return to rapture believers, then there will be a Thousand Year Reign. (something like that. Historic. Premils: please edit. Also, see Caleb's answer on the above [related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3131/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-millenialisms))

**What is the biblical basis for this belief?** Also, what logical deductions that support this belief can you make from biblical passages?

If tradition can be a convincing argument, feel free to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in Historical Premillennialism(mouthful) (Edit: Now I stand with Dispensation Premillennialism.) and I will use bullet points and passages after it to give the bases.

- Evil will increase

> Luke 17, [20] Once, on being asked by the Pharisees when the kingdom of God would come, Jesus replied, “The coming of the kingdom of God is not something that can be observed,
>
> Luke 17, [28] “It was the same in the days of Lot. People were eating and drinking, buying and selling, planting and building. 29 But the day Lot left Sodom, fire and sulfur rained down from heaven and destroyed them all. [32] Remember Lot’s wife!

What was it like in the days of Lot? The passage, "Remember Lot's wife!" suggests that it is when Lot was in Sodom and Gomorrah.

> Genesis 13, [12] Abram lived in the land of Canaan, while Lot lived among the cities of  the plain and pitched his tents near Sodom. [13] Now the people of Sodom were wicked and were sinning greatly against the LORD.
>
> Genesis 18, [20] Then the LORD said, “The outcry against Sodom and Gomorrah is so great and their sin so grievous [21] that I will go down and see if what they have done is as bad as the outcry that has reached me. If not, I will know.”
>
> Genesis 19, [26] But Lot’s wife looked back, and she became a pillar of salt.

It is pretty obvious here that the end of times are linked with sin. This is further reinforced with another verse in Book of Luke:

> Luke 17, [26] “Just as it was in the days of Noah, so also will it be in the days of the Son of Man. [27] People were eating, drinking, marrying and being given in marriage up to the day Noah entered the ark. Then the flood came and destroyed them all.
>
> Genesis 6, [5] The LORD saw how great the wickedness of the human race had become on the earth, and that every inclination of the thoughts of the human heart was only evil all the time. [6] The LORD regretted that he had made human beings on the earth, and his heart was deeply troubled. [7] So the LORD said, “I will wipe from the face of the earth the human race I have created—and with them the animals, the birds and the creatures that move along the ground—for I regret that I have made them.” [8] But Noah found favor in the eyes of the LORD.

- Great Tribulation

Tribulation refers to the hard times for the believers of Christ. There are disagreements on whether now is the time of tribulation or not. However, in America, the forces of Christianity are slowly decreasing. People are getting more wicked, to the point where they begin to arrest people when reciting bible publicly; to the point where in UK they began to teach health on Human Reproduction by showing *physical sexual intercourse video* (aka pornography, Google it if you don't believe me.)

> Luke 17 [30] “It will be just like this on the day the Son of Man is revealed. [31] On that day no one who is on the housetop, with possessions inside, should go down to get them. Likewise, no one in the field should go back for anything. [32] Remember Lot’s wife! [33] Whoever tries to keep their life will lose it, and whoever loses their life will preserve it. [34] I tell you, on that night two people will be in one bed; one will be taken and the other left. [35] Two women will be grinding grain together; one will be taken and the other left.”
>
> Matthew 24 [3] As Jesus was sitting on the Mount of Olives, the disciples came to him privately. “Tell us,” they said, “when will this happen, and what will be the sign of your coming and of the end of the age?” [4] Jesus answered: “Watch out that no one deceives you. [5] For many will come in my name, claiming, ‘I am the Messiah,’ and will deceive many. [6] You will hear of wars and rumors of wars, but see to it that you are not alarmed. Such things must happen, but the end is still to come. [7] Nation will rise against nation, and kingdom against kingdom. There will be famines and earthquakes in various places. [8] All these are the beginning of birth pains. [9] “Then you will be handed over to be persecuted and put to death, and you will be hated by all nations because of me. [10] At that time many will turn away from the faith and will betray and hate each other, [11] and many false prophets will appear and deceive many people. [12] Because of the increase of wickedness, the love of most will grow cold, [13] but the one who stands firm to the end will be saved. [14] And this gospel of the kingdom will be preached in the whole world as a testimony to all nations, and then the end will come. [15] “So when you see standing in the holy place ‘the abomination that causes desolation,’ spoken of through the prophet Daniel—let the reader understand— [16] then let those who are in Judea flee to the mountains. [17] Let no one on the housetop go down to take anything out of the house. [18] Let no one in the field go back to get their cloak. [19] How dreadful it will be in those days for pregnant women and nursing mothers! [20] Pray that your flight will not take place in winter or on the Sabbath. [21] For then there will be great distress, unequaled from the beginning of the world until now—and never to be equaled again.

Matt 24: 3 to 6: I don't know about you, but I think the state of today reflects this verse.

Matt 24: 7: You remember the tsunami hitting on Japan, with Reactors exploding, etc, right? many people in Japan are migrating because the island is slowly sinking, according to the geologists. They say another one is coming.

Matt 24: 14: There is no nation which the Gospel of God and missionaries weren't sent to according to the experts. We sent them all. The only problem is to give every person the chance to repent.

- Return of Christ

> Matt 24: [26] “So if anyone tells you, ‘There he is, out in the wilderness,’ do not go out; or, ‘Here he is, in the inner rooms,’ do not believe it. [27] For as lightning that comes from the east is visible even in the west, so will be the coming of the Son of Man. [28] Wherever there is a carcass, there the vultures will gather. [29] “Immediately after the distress of those days
>
> “‘the sun will be darkened, 
>      and the moon will not give its light; 
>   the stars will fall from the sky, 
>      and the heavenly bodies will be shaken.’
>
> [30] “Then will appear the sign of the Son of Man in heaven. And then all the peoples of the earth will mourn when they see the Son of Man coming on the clouds of heaven, with power and great glory. [31] And he will send his angels with a loud trumpet call, and they will gather his elect from the four winds, from one end of the heavens to the other.

- 1000 year Reign

> Revelation 20: [1] And I saw an angel coming down out of heaven, having the key to the Abyss and holding in his hand a great chain. [2] He seized the dragon, that ancient serpent, who is the devil, or Satan, and bound him for a thousand years. [3] He threw him into the Abyss, and locked and sealed it over him, to keep him from deceiving the nations anymore until the thousand years were ended. After that, he must be set free for a short time.
>   [4] I saw thrones on which were seated those who had been given authority to judge. And I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded because of their testimony about Jesus and because of the word of God. They had not worshiped the beast or its image and had not received its mark on their foreheads or their hands. They came to life and reigned with Christ a thousand years. [5] (The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were ended.) This is the first resurrection. [6] Blessed and holy are those who share in the first resurrection. The second death has no power over them, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with him for a thousand years.

Edit: As Caleb have said, my answer may not have any defense that holds this over all other views of the End. However, this question was asking for the biblical bases of this particular view, and besides, Jesus prophesies these events in SAME order on every other Gospels, least, I think so..

Edit: Yes. Matthew 24: 1 ~ 31, Mark 13: 1 ~ 26, Luke 17: 20 ~ 30. All of them list the things to come, in this particular order:

The Power of Satan Arising over the Churches and Followers of Christ --> Great Hardship for the followers of Christ --> Coming of Christ in Great Glory and Power.

Edit: (Again, as I said above, I stand with Dispensational Premillennialism. The Power of Satan Arising over the Churches and Followers of Christ --> The Rapture --> Great Hardship for the people of the world --> Coming of Christ in Great Glory and Power.

> Luke 17 [30] “It will be just like this on the day the Son of Man is revealed. [31] On that day no one who is on the housetop, with possessions inside, should go down to get them. Likewise, no one in the field should go back for anything. [32] Remember Lot’s wife! [33] Whoever tries to keep their life will lose it, and whoever loses their life will preserve it. [34] I tell you, on that night two people will be in one bed; one will be taken and the other left. [35] Two women will be grinding grain together; one will be taken and the other left.”

Due to that fact that Jesus said that some will be taken, and some will be left behind, it suggests that Rapture will take place first and then Tribulation will take place.)

Comment: ah, this answer is excellent! Now of course I'll have to ask (or find an already asked) question on how you guys explain the AD 70 theory (or maybe, how we [amils/postmils] explain it)

Comment: @ThomasShields thank you for the compliment... but I never heard of AD 70 theory. :P Care to explain?

Comment: Oh, it's the idea that much of the apocalyptic language of the NT is referring to the destruction of the temple in AD 70, rather than the tribulation. I guess it would need more defending than attacking, though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think this answer really provides a basis for the view. It points out a number of things that are consistent with it, but those things are also consistent with some of the other views on this issue. I don't see anything here that defends this view (which I happen to also hold) over and above other interpretations or that actually provide the basis or foundation for it.

Comment: @Caleb If you will notice... Jesus prophecies these events in *same order* as written on other Gospels. Doesn't that suggest something? :)

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog: I'm not sure you caught my point. Something that holds equally true for more than one view cannot be be "basis" for one of those views. Whatever hermeneutics get applied here, you must demonstrate what leads to THIS view, not just any view. Your argument is approximately like answering "Well first God created the world, then Adam fell, then Jesus died on the cross, rose and left, then someday he will come back." All millennial views agree on that anyway. The point of this question is to define how people arrive at THIS view in particular.

Comment: @Caleb Alright, alright. For the past four days, I dug up information that proves this view. Want to know about it? Ask for it on the site, like "what is the biblical proof for Historical Premil" or something like that. Then you will see my answer. This question here asks only for the biblical bases of this view, not how this view is the truth.