# The extent of different approaches to Revelation

Tags: eschatology, revelation

There are of course a number of different approaches to, and interpretations of the book of Revelation. When I read theological works on end times I stumble upon some of those. But I never really understand how widespread those are.

Approaches: Idealist approach, the futurist approach, the church historical approach and the preterist approach (among others).

Different views on the millennium: Historic premillennialism, premillennialism (and dispensialism), postmillennialism and amillennialism.

What I am interested in is some statistics of *present day Christianity*. Are there any estimates on how many people that support those different approaches and views on the millennium (I'm most curious of the later). And what kind of Christians do generally hold on to which view?

Comment: It's a big question so even if you only can give a part of an answer - That's great. :)

Comment: The following is not statistics, but Mike's answer to [Study Sources of Book of Revelation](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/8907) lists who supports what view (based on the books they've written.)

Comment: Oh. That's great. I look into it.

Comment: Related background for those who don't know what the different millennium views are about: [What are the differences between the different millenialisms?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3774/30)

Comment: It's going to be very hard to include historic Christianity in these figures because the edges between views have shifted and it's very hard to categorize many old Theologions using our current understanding of terms.

Comment: @Caleb I misread your comment at first. I'm mostly interested in present day Christianity. I do think the history of those different views/approaches are interesting. But that's another question. But I don't think the statistic of historic Christianity is that interesting. I have updated the question.

Comment: I figured the bounty would've drawn some more attention to this

Answer (score 1):

I have still not found any good answer to this question. But I post some hints that have been helpful to me. Hoping that it might be helpful for someone else and maybe intriguing to give a better answer. The following is a quotation from Steve Gregg, *Revelation - four views*, 1997, p. 33-34.

> **The contemporary conservative protestant scene**
>
> Conservative Protestants commentaries (those that not follow the
>   literary-critical approach) in the 19th and 20th centuries have been
>   divided:
>     The historicist approach continued into the 19th century in
>   the writings of E. B. Elliott (*Horae Apocalypticae*, 1847), A. J.
>   Gordon, Albert Barnes, and others. To my knowledge, the only modern
>   commentaries that espouse this view have not come from recognized
>   scholars (not that this fact should condemn them), but from
>   essentially self-published authors who are desirous to reintroduce
>   this viewpoint to a modern readership. Eugene Boring would seem to be
>   correct when he writes, "Although widely held by Protestant
>   interpreters after the Reformation and into the twentieth century, no
>   critical New Testament scholar today advocates this view."   The
>   *preterist* approach was followed in the 19th century by Moses Stuart (1845), and in the early 20th century by James Snowden (1919).
>   Preterism has had a recent resurgence in the writings of Christian
>   Reconstructionists like David Chilton and Kenneth Gentry.   On of the
>   first popular presentations of the *futurist* approach, and the most
>   influential, was that of J. A. Seiss (*Lectures on the Apocalypse*,
>   1909). In the 20th century, the *futurist* approach to Revelation has
>   become most common - especially since the publication of the
>   phenomenally successful *The Late Great Planet Earth*, by Hal Lindsey
>   - having its place almost in the very common stock of American pop culture. *Futurism* has been advocated by sound scholars, such as
>   Walvoord, Mounce, and Ladd, as well as by innumerable cranks and
>   eschatelogical faddists, who have often given it a bad name by their
>   repeated speculations concerning the date of the Second Coming and
>   their assigning of correspondences between the symbolic visions and
>   specific developments in an ever-changing modern political milieu.
>   The *spiritual* approach has received wide acceptance in modern
>   commentaries, though various labels have been attached to it. Since
>   Eichhorn, in the 18th century the dramatic nature of the book has
>   intrigues many students of the book. In 1939, William Hendriksen
>   popularized this view in his book, *More Than Conquerors*, though it
>   was found in a number of works earlier in the 20th century as well. As
>   I write, there appear to be more new commentaries published advocating
>   a *dramatico-spiritual* approach to Revelation than there are
>   advocating any of the other conservative approaches.

Authors emphasis. All spelling mistakes are (probably) mine. I do, by the way, highly recommend this book (even though I only started).